# What file properties affect the size of a video file?

Tags: video, windows-11, size

This question is related to one I just [posted on *Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77993489/in-windows-11-shell-what-does-the-file-property-video-compression-mean) about the meaning of the Windows shell file property "Video compression".

For a set of 71 video files, I'm looking at their properties, as reported by the Windows 11 shell. For information on those properties in general, see the *StackOverflow* Q&A, [*What are the file properties in the Windows 11 shell*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78068319/what-are-the-file-properties-in-the-windows-11-shell)?

This question is about the properties that appear to be relevant to the size of a video file. The ones I've identified for that are:

```
  1   Size (in bytes)
 27   Length (i.e., duration)
316   Frame width
314   Frame height
315   Frame rate (in frames / sec)
 28   Bit rate
313   Data rate (in kb / sec)
320   Total bitrate (in kb / sec)
311   Video compression
```

For a first approach, I figured the size of a video file ought to relate to the total number of pixels represented by the whole file. So, for each file, I calculated the size per pixel as megabytes per gigapixel as follows:

```
Mb/Gpixel = (Size / 1024 ^ 2) / (Frame width * Frame height * Frame rate * Length * 60 * 60 * 24 / 1e9)
```

If this number were fairly constant across any one file type, that would mean that the file sizes would depend fairly reliably on the combination of frame size, frame rate, and duration. But this number is far from constant. Among the 45 mp4's in the set of files, it ranges from 2.6 to 63. Among 17 wmv's, it ranges from 6.3 to 50. Clearly, something else is having a large effect.

The properties that are left after the above are Bit rate, Data rate, Total bitrate, and Video compression. I don't understand any of these properties, so I don't know how to calculate what their effects might be, but from the table below, they also don't appear to be controlling the file sizes.

The table below gives the data for the 45 mp4 files in descending order of "Mb/Gpixel" showing the wide variation of the three remaining rates. The right-most column is the number of the Video compression property discussed in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77993489/in-windows-11-shell-what-does-the-file-property-video-compression-mean). It is 6 for all the files, except the second file, for which it's 3.

| Mb | Length | Width | Height | Fr/sec | Mb/Gpixel | Bit rt | Data kb/s | Total kb/s | Vid comp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22.9 | 00:05:18 | 320 | 240 | 15 | 62.5 | 99 | 500 | 599 | 6 |
| 597.6 | 01:30:39 | 400 | 224 | 19.93 | 61.5 | 128 | 788 | 916 | 3 |
| 480.3 | 00:59:18 | 368 | 272 | 29.97 | 45.0 | 128 | 999 | 1,127 | 6 |
| 105.2 | 00:07:24 | 640 | 360 | 25 | 41.1 | 256 | 1,727 | 1,983 | 6 |
| 33.6 | 00:07:48 | 320 | 240 | 30 | 31.2 | 99 | 500 | 600 | 6 |
| 1154.3 | 01:59:55 | 640 | 360 | 24 | 29.0 | 255 | 1,086 | 1,342 | 6 |
| 1507.3 | 01:59:55 | 720 | 486 | 24 | 24.9 | 255 | 1,497 | 1,753 | 6 |
| 150.1 | 00:56:13 | 320 | 240 | 25 | 23.2 | 125 | 242 | 368 | 6 |
| 822.3 | 01:52:00 | 640 | 360 | 24 | 22.1 | 256 | 766 | 1,022 | 6 |
| 251.5 | 01:42:05 | 320 | 240 | 29.97 | 17.8 | 109 | 230 | 339 | 6 |
| 33.7 | 00:04:37 | 640 | 360 | 30 | 17.6 | 61 | 957 | 1,019 | 6 |
| 124.8 | 00:46:41 | 426 | 240 | 25 | 17.4 | 125 | 242 | 368 | 6 |
| 922.4 | 01:52:00 | 720 | 486 | 24 | 16.3 | 256 | 883 | 1,139 | 6 |
| 39.0 | 00:07:57 | 480 | 360 | 29.97 | 15.8 | 61 | 620 | 681 | 6 |
| 349.4 | 00:07:24 | 1920 | 1080 | 25 | 15.2 | 256 | 6,341 | 6,597 | 6 |
| 349.4 | 00:07:24 | 1920 | 1080 | 25 | 15.2 | 256 | 6,341 | 6,597 | 6 |
| 12.2 | 00:06:40 | 400 | 224 | 23.98 | 14.2 | 47 | 203 | 251 | 6 |
| 215.0 | 00:50:35 | 320 | 568 | 29.79 | 13.1 | 93 | 491 | 584 | 6 |
| 32.7 | 00:06:41 | 640 | 360 | 29.97 | 11.8 | 61 | 618 | 679 | 6 |
| 254.1 | 00:13:20 | 1280 | 720 | 29.97 | 11.5 | 159 | 2,496 | 2,656 | 6 |
| 24.0 | 00:06:20 | 640 | 360 | 24 | 11.4 | 128 | 397 | 525 | 6 |
| 53.5 | 00:10:53 | 640 | 470 | 25 | 10.9 | 111 | 570 | 682 | 6 |
| 173.5 | 00:52:31 | 480 | 360 | 29.97 | 10.6 | 125 | 330 | 455 | 6 |
| 172.6 | 00:52:16 | 480 | 360 | 29.97 | 10.6 | 123 | 331 | 455 | 6 |
| 15.1 | 00:04:21 | 640 | 360 | 23.97 | 10.5 | 125 | 352 | 478 | 6 |
| 203.4 | 00:49:47 | 640 | 360 | 29.97 | 9.9 | 96 | 472 | 568 | 6 |
| 14.1 | 00:03:55 | 640 | 320 | 29.97 | 9.8 | 125 | 366 | 492 | 6 |
| 45.8 | 00:13:36 | 640 | 360 | 25 | 9.8 | 126 | 337 | 463 | 6 |
| 28.9 | 00:09:07 | 640 | 360 | 25 | 9.2 | 125 | 310 | 435 | 6 |
| 149.4 | 00:53:26 | 480 | 360 | 29.97 | 9.0 | 122 | 261 | 384 | 6 |
| 54.4 | 00:58:56 | 448 | 256 | 14.98 | 8.9 | 24 | 102 | 127 | 6 |
| 35.7 | 00:11:52 | 640 | 360 | 25 | 8.7 | 125 | 287 | 413 | 6 |
| 31.2 | 00:10:33 | 640 | 360 | 25 | 8.6 | 125 | 281 | 407 | 6 |
| 39.7 | 00:11:23 | 640 | 360 | 29.97 | 8.4 | 125 | 353 | 478 | 6 |
| 40.3 | 00:14:34 | 640 | 360 | 25 | 8.0 | 125 | 255 | 380 | 6 |
| 169.6 | 00:33:32 | 854 | 480 | 29.97 | 6.9 | 128 | 570 | 698 | 6 |
| 802.7 | 02:54:16 | 854 | 480 | 30 | 6.2 | 129 | 506 | 635 | 6 |
| 52.4 | 00:11:51 | 854 | 480 | 29.97 | 6.0 | 127 | 487 | 615 | 6 |
| 713.8 | 02:47:18 | 854 | 480 | 30 | 5.8 | 127 | 460 | 588 | 6 |
| 35.3 | 00:15:27 | 640 | 360 | 29.97 | 5.5 | 125 | 185 | 310 | 6 |
| 363.9 | 01:35:31 | 854 | 480 | 30 | 5.2 | 128 | 396 | 524 | 6 |
| 22.6 | 00:11:42 | 640 | 360 | 29.97 | 4.7 | 130 | 130 | 261 | 6 |
| 290.5 | 01:00:08 | 1024 | 576 | 29.97 | 4.6 | 127 | 538 | 666 | 6 |
| 19.1 | 00:03:27 | 1280 | 720 | 29.97 | 3.3 | 256 | 515 | 771 | 6 |
| 253.7 | 00:30:48 | 1920 | 1080 | 25 | 2.6 | 125 | 1,019 | 1,145 | 6 |

I don't see any correlation between the sizes of these files and their other file properties. Obviously, the frame width and height can't be completely irrelevant, but it appears that the most important factors, or at least some very important factors, are something other than the file properties I got from the shell.

My question is, what properties of a video file can I observe that determine its file size?

Comment: Friends don't let friends use VBA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaInfo GUI version here: https://mediaarea.net/download/binary/mediainfo-gui/24.01.1/MediaInfo_GUI_24.01.1_Windows.exe

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_compression_picture_types Video compression is far more complicated than a simple array of bitmaps see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_frame

Comment: @Gantendo - Interesting links. But both Wikipedia on MediaInfo and its own website don't say anything about reporting on use of compression in the file, such as what is in the article linked in your second comment, i.e., whether the file's frames are of type I, P, or B. That would seem to have a major effect on the size of the file. Is there a way to know that?

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and ffmpeg https://ffmpeg.org/

Comment: `ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -vf "showinfo" -f null -`  output will look like this https://i.imgur.com/IDW9EpV.png

Comment: And MediaInfo does report on compression used on both the video and audio data.

Comment: Number of pixels, frame rate and codec all affect the file size, but in addition the actual scenes being recorded make a big difference. The more the scene changes between frames, the larger the file will be. So don't expect to find a clear relationship between any metadata and the file size - unless you use a codec which sacrifices quality in order to get a constant bit rate output.

Comment: Resolution, Bitrate, Frame rate, Compression ratio, Color depth, Video length, HDR, WCG, and more.

Comment: +1 for careful analysis before submitting question.

Comment: To expand on @Paul 's comment, compression (and the resultant file size) is affected by the video content. A scene with a bare wall will require less data than a bookcase wall. The amount of action (movement) determines the amount of data for inter-frame differences. A stationary camera will tend to produce smaller video files compared to the same camera that is always moving or panning. There is no "*file attribute to correlate with size*" because the compression is affected by the content of the video (esp. motion or action).

Comment: @Gantendo - I posted a question that follows up on your comments. Would you please see if you know the answer? https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/37240/how-to-find-out-if-a-video-file-has-picture-types-p-and-or-b-and-uses-inter-fram

Comment: @Gantendo - You said that MediaInfo reports on compression used in both video and audio data. I ran MediaInfoOnline on a video file, and the only thing I see related to compression is in the Audio section, which has "Compression mode" listed as "Lossy". What field(s) in the video section are you referring to as reporting on video compression?

Comment: @NewSites https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec & https://i.imgur.com/7GLaQsQ.png

Comment: @Gantendo - That's interesting. You showed MediaInfo output that included in the Video section the field "Compression mode" with value "Lossy". As I said before, the video file I ran through MediaInfoOnline had that field and value in the Audio section, but no such field in the Video section. I wonder what it means when that field is absent. It can't mean no compression because the file is an mp4. In any case, the value of "Lossy" doesn't say much because that's just a huge category of codecs, right?

Comment: @Gantendo - Self-correction: I now see that MediaInfo has several fields about the codec used in the file. I didn't understand before that a codec is compression and decompression software, so that saying what codec is used implies everything there is to know about what compression technique is used. Have I got that right?

Comment: @NewSites As always, its more complicated than that https://videoconvert.minitool.com/video-converter/lossless-compressed-video-formats.html & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncompressed_video & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format

Comment: @NewSites So this is a codec (used for encoding and decoding) but it is lossless https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ut_Video_Codec_Suite (it does use compression but no data is destroyed)

Comment: A codec is for encoding and decoding. Many codecs compress, but that is not necessarily the case. Some compression is lossless and others use lossy compression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs#Non-compression_2

Comment: If I know that a video uses H.264 I still don't know if the person creating the file chose a specific bitrate for example. So you'd need a bunch of metadata to know exactly which settings the person who created the file used. In the case of peer to peer networks this information is sometimes provided in a little text file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.nfo

Comment: If you use Handbrake you can give it a try. It will give you a bunch of options other than the codec e.g. https://i.imgur.com/s2Kfonx.png